# Powershell to login a service account on a remote server

Tags: authentication, service, account

We have a number of Windows servers that have a service account to manage updates. The problem we have is we need the serivce account to log back after a reboot.

We need this often to complete updates. Currently the updates are not completing due to the login step not happening, and will not complete until a user\service account logs in to the server. This could cause problems for a live system if an outstanding update is applied and requires a reboot to complete.

I have done quite a bit of searching to see if this is possible, so far I do understand that this is possible, but I have not figured out how to do it remotely\or locally via a auto run script.